# Back-end services on LAMP

Tags: java, service, lamp

We are developing a web-client for a startup. We are thinking on different solutions. We need a guideline on how to handle back-end services. We are developing the web-client on LAMP stack. There are certain DB tasks that needs to be handled 24/7 at back-end. Would it be flexible enough to write those services in JAVA? We are really new with the implementation of LAMP stack. Any light on the topic is highly appreciated :)

Comment: Define "back-end services" - the question is very hazy at the moment. Why use two platforms? Why not use one language for the whole job?

Comment: If you are "new to LAMP" and are considering Java, why not just go down the Java route then? Linux / Jsf/Struts / GlassFish / MySQL

Comment: Dear Pekka Can we handle all the back-end services with PHP? By back-end services I mean some scheduled and triggered activities that needs to be run after a certain period of time 24/7. Although we have been developing on PHP since one year but most of the time we were using C# for writing windows services. The issue now is to write those services using LAMP stack. Can we write windows like services in linux and using PHP? Hope to hear you soon.

Answer (score 0):

If the back-end services are DB-tasks (sql scripts) and the like (scripts);  and you are using LAMP, that is linux; I think it is good enough to automated/schedule your backend scripts using [CRON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) .